# Triage queue is inconsistent in showing timestamps

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits, triage

While reviewing some posts in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review), I noticed the following in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/34524880):

[image: Timestamps in the triage queue aren't clear]

How dare on Earth an answer that was written 24 minutes ago has 2 or 3 weeks old comments? This can be pretty confusing to new people into reviewing in general or people who care for specific details. I know that this is an audit, but it should be more clear or at least more tricky.

[Again...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Ryb.png)

Comment: Oh yeah, I was to say, it was very probably an Audit... Then well, the "Purpose" of Audits is that **you** pay attention, then alright good-good, you were paying attention... Mission accomplished, I would think... (All/most Audits are complete *stupid*, no need to get upset about those...)

Comment: @chivracq Yeah, It was an audit, I think those audits should be a little bit harder (tricky) but yeah Mission Impossible is done.